# what does "->" mean in swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I was following a Swift tutorial, and in a function it is declared as:

```
func clamp (min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat, value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{}
```

what does -> mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called the **return arrow** and indicates that the function returns a value, whose type follows the `->`. It is optional (along with the type that follows it) if the function returns no value.

More info at [Defining and Calling Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_244)

Answer (score 1):

`->` denotes the type of a function's return value.

In your case, you are defining a function that returns a float value (although the function body is an empty body (`{}`), so it should give a compilation error since you are not returning any value).